# Cannot flash bricked Xiaomi

Tags: factory-reset, xiaomi

Device is Xiaomi Redmi 3S

During the last update (6.12.15) 3 days ago, the mobile bricked and cannot boot.

I cannot fastboot because the bootloader is locked and cannot be unlocked using 'minimal adb fastboot' (eom edl is not allowed)

I cannot do the recovery, because "reading device information fail"

I cannot paste rom file into internal memory, because without loaded OS it doesn't appear in connected PC.

If I try anything else, device gets stuck on Java error - systemuiservice error - UnknownFormatConversionException

I run out of options what to do and what I managed to google out.

Comment: If the device is Qualcomm-based, try activating its 9008 emergency mode and use MiFlash along with a corresponding image to revive it - it's probably the only option available. You might need a stripped USB wire for that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. As `Andy Yan` pointed me, I did it using 9008 Qualcomm mode. It still wasn't easy as I had to open the case, shortcut maintenance pins and find the right combination of flashing tool and firmware rom for my phone, but I did it. Case closed.